# Document getElementsByTagName XML not finding all element

Tags: java, xml, dom

As the title suggest I'm having an issue with the "getElementsByTagName" on the document class after i have read an XML file.

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/file/path");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(url .openStream());


NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
System.out.println(items.getLength());
```

The code above is working to some extent, the file I'm reading has around 17 thousand elements with the tagname I'm searching for but whatever i try it's only finding 8893 items always.

I have tried "random" stuff that comes up on stackoverflow regarding namespace searching etc and also just tried to increace the memory heap if that was an issue but nothing works.

Example of how the xml documents look:

```
<base-element>
    <sub-element1>
        <tagname id="x" classname="string">
            <attribute></attribute>
        </tagname>
        ...
    </sub-element1>
    <sub-element2>
        <tagname id="x" classname="string">
            <attribute></attribute>
        </tagname>
        ...
    </sub-element2>
</base-element>
```

And i need to find all the tagname in both sub-element 1 and 2. But currently the code is not event finding all of them in just one section, it's picking randomly.

Comment: "...17 thousand elements" -- Wow, and you're using DOM? For XML data of that size, wouldn't you be better off using SAX or StAX?

Comment: I'm new to java in general, so when searching for reading XML from URL this was the solution that came up multiple times. Got any links for SAX/STAX, difference and usage etc @HovercraftFullOfEels